# For each $\epsilon$, for which $\delta$ does $d(x,y)<\delta\implies d(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$ hold?

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces, compactness, uniform-convergence, collatz-conjecture

I have the definition : A function from a metric space to a metric space is uniformly continuous if for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta$ such that $d(x,y)<\delta\implies d(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$.

Therefore for each $\epsilon$ we can identify some unique largest $\delta$ for which the implication always holds.  What are the values of $\underline\delta=\lim \sup \delta(\epsilon)$ for each corresponding  $\epsilon$ in the following case?

Let $X=\Bbb Z[\frac16], d$ where $d(x,y)=\lvert x-y\rvert_2$, the 2-adic metric.

Then let $f:X\to X$

$f(x)=\begin{cases}3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)}&x>0\\f(x)=0&x=0\\3x-2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)}&x<0\end{cases}$

Now I believe I've determined $f$ is continuous and since $X$ inherits its topology from a compact space that should make $f$ uniformly continuous.  So I want to verify this either algebraically or with some values and determine which delta and epsilon correspond.

But I'm not getting results that obviously confirm the proposition.  For example , for pairs $(x,y)$ I get the following results for the corresponding ceiling/floor on delta and epsilon:

$(5,85): \underline\delta(\frac1{16})=\frac18$

$(13,53): \underline\delta(\frac18)=\frac18$

$(21,85): \underline\delta(\frac12)=\frac1{64}$

> So I'm beginning to doubt the premise that $f$ is continuous.  What is the $\delta$ for each $\epsilon$, or else where did I going wrong in understanding and determining continuity of $f$?

---

Here's my argument of continuity of $f$:

Firstly, by reflectivity of both the function and the metric around $0$ we can ignore negative values and prove for non-negative values without loss of generality.

As a function from the odd numbers onto the odd numbers $f(x)=(3x+1)\lvert3x+1\rvert_2$ is discontinuous only at $-\frac13$ where $f(-\frac13)=0$

Then extending the same map to any isobar of $\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ by perserving its powers of $2$ as follows: $f(2^nx)=2^nf(x)$ is only discontinuous at $f(-\frac{2^m}{3})=0:m\in\Bbb Z$

Then modifying the map to eliminate the leaves of its graph, and at the same time eliminate maps into $0$ we have $f(x)=3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)}$ which should be continuous.  However I'm unsure, perhaps the continuous map is:

$f(x)=(3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)})\lvert3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)}\rvert_2$

Comment: A) $f$ is not continuous at $0$ and cannot even be made continuous there by redefining $f(0)$. B) Even if one had a function that is uniformly continuous, the best thing one could ask for is the maximum or supremum of all delta's which work for a given epsilon, which would produce something one could call a function $\delta(\epsilon)$. What meaningful purpose that would serve is beyond me. But as said, $f$ does not even satisfy a necessary precondition for such a question.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg this is my hypothesis, that I have wrongly assessed uniform continuity. Is the proof of your claim that it is not continuous assumptive or definitive, and is it simple? As for my aim, I am scrutining precisely the structure of this function around $0$ which can only approach $0$ through the net $2^n3^m$ where $m$ is fixed and $n$ ascending.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg it is my belief that near $0$ this function is arbitrarily close to the function $f(x)=4x$ and that makes it continuous. Can my mistake be broken down into which of those two statements is false?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thank-you for the better definition of $\underline\delta=\lim \sup \delta(\epsilon)$ I've also modified $f$ slightly to tie up one element of uncertainty I had sur.rounding the effect of negative values on continuity, and proposed an alternative function $f$ at the end which may be what is needed.

Comment: Oh sorry, the original function $f$ **is** continuous at $0$. I was confused because sometimes there's talk of $2^{v_2}$ and sometimes $2^{-v_2}$, and I must have thought of the latter.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg thank-you for clarifying. I "get" the intuitive result but I can't show the rigorous form.  That $f$ only yields sequences converging to $0$ via the set $2^m3^n$ is equivalent to the Collatz conjecture and I remain convinced that this is close to a proof for somebody with the right skills...  $0$ being bounded by $f(x)=4x$ as $f$ approaches it is also equivalent to the Collatz conjecture. I will get there in the end but it takes time... next to learn about sequentially compact I guess...

Comment: However, now Ithink that $f$ is not continuous at 3, and presumably most other points. Namely, $f(3) = 12$ whereas for $n \ge 1$, $f(3+2^n) = 9 + 3\cdot 2^n + 1$ which converges 2-adically to 10. (And the same counterexample works for the revised $f$, where $f(3) = 3$ but $f(3+2^n)$ goes to 5.) The crucial point is that the 3-adic value has no reason to be continuous w.r.t. the 2-adic value, and at many points is not.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thank-you, that is most helpful. The numbers equivalent to $\equiv\pm1\pmod6$ are a sufficient set for which to prove the conjecture as the whole net $2^m3^nx$ provably converges together so this means I need to use those instead of $\Bbb Z[\frac16]$

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg sorry to push for more info but I'm slowly getting to grips with these concepts.  Suppose we make cosets $x=2^m3^n\cdot[x]$ of $x\in\Bbb Z[\frac16]$ indexed by the numbers equivalent to $\pm1\pmod 6$. Then *this* should be continuous (and $f([x])$ directed to $[1]$). Does that sound like hogwash in any way?

Comment: It does not sound like math terminology used in a sensible way. Please study the concept of quotients of algebraic structures (groups, rings,...), at least up to where you understand how a map defined on e.g. a group might induce a map on a quotient, but has to satisfy certain criteria for that. Once you have gone through enough exercises to know your routine of checking such criteria, as every student of basic algebra can, you should be able to phrase your question in comprehensible terminology, see if it makes sense at all, and in that case most likely you'll easily find an answer yourself.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg OK will do, thanks. The cosets are multiplicative while the function still makes use of addition and the fn $p^{\nu_p(x)}$ so I wonder how far beyond basic texts this is.

Answer (score 2):

> For each $\epsilon$, for which $\delta$ does $d(x,y)<\delta\implies d(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$?

According to this, if you choose a particular pair $(x,y)$ and calculate $d(x,y)$ and $d(f(x),f(y)),$
$\delta$ must be *greater* than  $d(x,y)$ and $\epsilon$ must be greater than $d(f(x),f(y)).$
How do you get values to which $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ must be *equal?*

In general there is no reason to expect that $d(x,y)$ will be a function of $d(f(x),f(y)),$
let alone a one-to-one function.
The mere fact that you have three points that don’t fit whatever pattern you expected them to fit is meaningless.

——

**Update:**
Since the question has changed, I’ll address some of the new points raised.

> Therefore for each $\epsilon$ we can identify some unique $\delta$ for which the implication always holds.

That is true if you delete the word “unique.” Consider $\mathbb R$ with the usual metric, and consider a constant function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R.$
The function is uniformly continuous, but any  positive $\delta$ suffices. What makes any value of delta “unique”?

> What are the values of $\underline\delta=\lim \sup \delta(\epsilon)$ for each corresponding  $\epsilon$ in the following case?

In the example I just gave, you could take the lim inf (*not* lim sup) of $\delta,$ which would be $0$ for any positive $\epsilon.$
Note that the lim inf is not itself a value of $\delta$ that satisfies the condition.

You cannot find the lim inf (or lim sup) of $\delta$ for any particular $\epsilon$ merely by looking at one pair $(x,y).$

Also note that the same comment that suggested there might be a minimum or maximum $\delta$ also gave the opinion that this result would be useless.

In fact, what your three examples of
$\underline\delta(\epsilon)$ appear to show is that your treatment of $\underline\delta$ is incorrect.

Comment: I never spoke of a lim sup, which does not make sense here anyway. My idea was, if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a uniformly continuous map of metric spaces, then for each $\epsilon >0$ the set $\Delta(\epsilon) := \lbrace \delta \in \Bbb R: \forall x,y \in X, d_X(x_1,x_2) < \delta \Rightarrow d_Y(f(x_1), f(x_2)) < \epsilon \rbrace$ contains elements > 0, hence has a supremum > 0, which here (because of the discrete values the metric attains) would be a maximum. Sending each $\epsilon$ to each thus defined "best possible $\delta$ for this $\epsilon$" was what I thought the OP might have in mind.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I was drawing upom this http://theanalysisofdata.com/probability/B_3.html just below definition B.3.2 it talks of a unique $\delta$ for each $\epsilon$ which I interpret to mean what you wrote. It sounds like a maximum / supremum is the better name for it.

Comment: @RobertFrost There is no mention of a "unique" $\delta$ on that page. It uses the somewhat ambiguous words "single $\delta$ for each $\epsilon,$" which signify merely that it once you choose an $\epsilon$ it is possible to identify (not necessarily uniquely!) some value of $\delta$ that satisfies the condition for every $x$ and $y,$ rather than having to choose $x$ (or $y$) before identifying a value of $\delta.$

Comment: @DavidK I think we're both interpreting the term "single" as synonymous with "unique per $\epsilon$ (independently of $x\in X$)".

Comment: @RobertFrost No, _you_ may be doing so but I absolutely do not. "Unique" has a special meaning in this context; it implies there is some quality that _only this value_ of $\delta$ has and no other $\delta$ has it. No such quality is mentioned in the definition. Instead, once you have chosen $\epsilon$ you have _many_ choices of $\delta.$ In general, for some arbitrary uniformly continuous function, there may be no "best" choice of $\delta$ for a given $\epsilon.$

Comment: @DavidK I'm concerned I don't understand this properly as this is my first introduction to the concept but it seems fairly clear that the definition means there can be a range of $\delta$ for any given $\epsilon$ but there is categorically a unique ceiling, maximum or supremum on $\delta$ for any given $\epsilon$ and that seems to be the whole point of the concept of uniform continuity - that there IS always a choice of $\delta$ which can be made even without knowing $x$. I keep re-reading it and can't see another interpretation.

Comment: No, there is not necessarily a maximum (a constant function is uniformly continuous, for example), and finding the maximum (if it exists) is _not the point at all._ Some introductory calculus books reinforce misconceptions by taking the trouble to calculate a maximum $\delta$ for a few easy examples when it is not needed.

Comment: @DavidK ok i'll give it some more thought

Comment: There is, of course, a kind of continuity proof in which you prove that a suitable $\delta$ exists for every $\epsilon$ by finding some function $h$ such that setting $\delta = h(\epsilon)$ satisfies the definition. But $h$ does not need to be $\underline\delta.$ Setting $\delta = \frac12\underline\delta(\epsilon)$ works just as well, or you could even come up with a function that has no obvious relationship to $\underline\delta$ except that it never produces an output that's too large. It's often good to choose a function you _know_ is smaller than needed so the calculations are simpler.

Answer (score 0):

What is $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{6}]$ and is $\nu_2$(x)? I'm not familiar with that notation. Also, if a function is uniformly continuous, the $\delta$ only depends on $\epsilon$. I suspect that since $\mathbb{Z}$ is discrete, you can pick $\delta$ < 1, but that depends on the definition of X.

Comment: $\Bbb Z[\frac16]$ is the set of all rationals not permitting negative powers of any prime greater than $3$ in their factorisation.  $n=\nu_p(x)$ is the highest exponent $n$ such that $p^n$ factors $x$.  So $2^{\nu_2(28)}=4$